# VS 2017 AWS Lamda Publish error Max version supported by netcoreapp1.0 is 1.6.0

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, aws-lambda

I am trying to publish from VA 2017 to AWS Lambda. It was working before updated some packages via NuGet.

I am now getting this following error:

```
Project is referencing NETStandard.Library version 1.6.1. Max version supported by netcoreapp1.0 is 1.6.0.
```

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to downgrade the .net core version using package manager console command:

```
Install-Package NETStandard.Library -Version 1.6.0
```

Worked